# How can i get object from TMXTiledMap and store it in Dictionary variable ?

Tags: android, tiles, cocos2d-iphone, tilemap, cocos2d-x

I've been following a tutorial to make tiled map in cocos2d x 3.0 ,
but i couldnt complete the rest of the tutorial because its for coco2d x 2.0 version,

How can i get a value of property that is stored in an object from TMXObjectGroup variable ?
and my code is:

```
tileMap = cocos2d::TMXTiledMap::create("ground.tmx");
ground = tileMap->layerNamed("ground");
this->addChild(tileMap);

TMXObjectGroup *objects = tileMap->getObjectGroup("objects");
??? sign = objects->getObject("sign");// it return ValueMap not Dictionary ?!
```

how can i get a Dictionary of that object so i can get its values ??

Comment: It would have been nice if there was an answer to this

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueMap sign = objects->getObject("sign");
float x = sign["x"].asFloat();
float y = sign["y"].asFloat();
std::string nameAlias =  sign["name_alias"].asString();
```

ValueMap in cocos2d contains Value type. You can see in CCValue.h for more details.